# How to perform Eclipse repository mirroring for offline installation Maven plugin?

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin

I set up **Maven** for offline development, as described here - [How do I configure Maven for offline development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7233328/how-do-i-configure-maven-for-offline-development/7233578#7233578)
Now I want to install **Maven** plugin for **Eclipse** in offline mode.

The plugin can be installed via online update site. But how to install it in offline mode?
I tried to install it in the "Install New Software" menu so -

```
jar:file:/C:/plugins/apache-maven-3.1.0-bin.zip!/
```

Of course, it has given nothing.

As described here - [Downloading Eclipse plug-in update sites for offline installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371176/downloading-eclipse-plug-in-update-sites-for-offline-installation) - and here - [Equinox p2 Repository Mirroring](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_p2_Repository_Mirroring) - I can use a repository mirroring (update sites **Eclipse** plugins).

This code -

```
$eclipse_home/eclipse -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository.mirrorApplication -source $1 -destination $2
$eclipse_home/eclipse -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository.mirrorApplication -source $1 -destination $2
```

How can I use it to install the plugin **Maven**? What specify in the arguments  `$1` and `$2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that you want to install m2e (maven plugin for eclipse). You should be installing from the following update site:

```
http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases
```

So, assuming that you want to mirror it at `C:\Eclipse\repos`, the command will look like this:

```
$eclipse_home/eclipse.exe -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository.mirrorApplication \
  -source http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases \
  -destination C:\Eclipse\repos
```