# How to prepare Eclipse m2e configurators for offline installation?

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e

How to prepare Eclipse m2e configurators for offline installation?

This is question after [How to preinstall Eclipse m2e configurators (Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36824645/how-to-preinstall-eclipse-m2e-configurators-plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lif)

Trying to hack gives (see below) that they are actually inside Maven Central repository. While there may be a way to get list of them and cached within local Maven repository (or local net Nexus server), there is still question how to install into Eclipse.

UPDATE. Becuase of using maven plugins, the answer for [How to perform Eclipse repository mirroring for offline installation Maven plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18686630/how-to-perform-eclipse-repository-mirroring-for-offline-installation-maven-plugi) can't be used.

Raised as https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=492449

**Details:**

"Window > Preferences > Maven > Discovery" is using

http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/discovery/directory-1.6.xml

Has content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<directory xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/discovery/directory/">
    <entry url="http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/.m2e/discovery-catalog/org.eclipse.m2e.discovery.oss-catalog-1.6.jar" permitCategories="true"/>
</directory>
```

While the *catalog*.jar has pairs of files like

1) lifecycle/org.eclipse.m2e.discovery.lifecycles.tycho.pluginxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!--
    =================== DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE ====================
    Generated by M2E Discovery Publisher 0.4.1 on 2015-10-30 22:29:48,
    any modifications will be overwritten.
    ==============================================================
    -->
    <plugin>
      <extension point="org.eclipse.m2e.core.lifecycleMappings">
        <lifecycleMapping id="org.sonatype.tycho.m2e.tychoLifecycleMapping" name="Tycho Build Lifecycle Mapping" class="org.sonatype.tycho.m2e.internal.TychoLifecycleMapping"></lifecycleMapping>
      </extension>
      <extension point="org.eclipse.m2e.core.projectConfigurators">
        <configurator id="maven-bundle-plugin" name="Project Configurator for maven-bundle-plugin osgi-bundle projects" class="org.sonatype.tycho.m2e.felix.internal.MavenBundlePluginConfigurator"></configurator>
        <configurator id="pde-maven-bundle-plugin" name="PDE integration for maven-bundle-plugin projects" class="org.sonatype.tycho.m2e.internal.PDEMavenBundlePluginConfigurator" secondaryTo="maven-bundle-plugin"></configurator>
      </extension>
    </plugin>
```

2) lifecycle\org.eclipse.m2e.discovery.lifecycles.tycho.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  <lifecycleMappingMetadata>    <lifecycleMappings>
    <lifecycleMapping>
      <packagingType>eclipse-plugin</packagingType>
      <lifecycleMappingId>org.sonatype.tycho.m2e.tychoLifecycleMapping</lifecycleMappingId>
    </lifecycleMapping>
    <lifecycleMapping>
      <packagingType>eclipse-test-plugin</packagingType>
      <lifecycleMappingId>org.sonatype.tycho.m2e.tychoLifecycleMapping</lifecycleMappingId>
    </lifecycleMapping>
    <lifecycleMapping>
      <packagingType>eclipse-feature</packagingType>
      <lifecycleMappingId>org.sonatype.tycho.m2e.tychoLifecycleMapping</lifecycleMappingId>
    </lifecycleMapping>
    <lifecycleMapping>
      <packagingType>eclipse-update-site</packagingType>
      <lifecycleMappingId>org.sonatype.tycho.m2e.tychoLifecycleMapping</lifecycleMappingId>
    </lifecycleMapping>
    <lifecycleMapping>
      <packagingType>eclipse-application</packagingType>
      <lifecycleMappingId>org.sonatype.tycho.m2e.tychoLifecycleMapping</lifecycleMappingId>
    </lifecycleMapping>
    <lifecycleMapping>
      <packagingType>eclipse-repository</packagingType>
      <lifecycleMappingId>org.sonatype.tycho.m2e.tychoLifecycleMapping</lifecycleMappingId>
      <pluginExecutions>
        <pluginExecution>
          <pluginExecutionFilter>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <versionRange>[0.9.0,)</versionRange>
            <goals>
              <goal>clean</goal>
            </goals>
          </pluginExecutionFilter>
          <action>
            <ignore />
          </action>
        </pluginExecution>
      </pluginExecutions>
    </lifecycleMapping>
    <lifecycleMapping>
      <packagingType>bundle</packagingType>
      <lifecycleMappingId>org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.JarLifecycleMapping</lifecycleMappingId>
    </lifecycleMapping>       </lifecycleMappings>    <pluginExecutions>
    <pluginExecution>
      <pluginExecutionFilter>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
        <artifactId>tycho-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <versionRange>[0.12.0,)</versionRange>
        <goals>
          <goal>compile</goal>
          <goal>testCompile</goal>
        </goals>
        <parameters>
          <compilerId>jdt</compilerId>
        </parameters>
      </pluginExecutionFilter>
      <action>
        <ignore />
      </action>
    </pluginExecution>
    <pluginExecution>
      <pluginExecutionFilter>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
        <artifactId>tycho-packaging-plugin</artifactId>
        <versionRange>[0.12.0,)</versionRange>
        <goals>
          <goal>build-qualifier-aggregator</goal>
          <goal>build-qualifier</goal>
          <goal>validate-id</goal>
          <goal>validate-version</goal>
        </goals>
      </pluginExecutionFilter>
      <action>
        <ignore />
      </action>
    </pluginExecution>
    <pluginExecution>
      <pluginExecutionFilter>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
        <versionRange>[1.0.0,)</versionRange>
        <goals>
          <goal>manifest</goal>
          <goal>bundle</goal>
        </goals>
      </pluginExecutionFilter>
      <action>
        <configurator>
          <id>maven-bundle-plugin</id>
        </configurator>
      </action>
    </pluginExecution>
    <pluginExecution>
      <pluginExecutionFilter>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
        <versionRange>[1.0.0,)</versionRange>
        <goals>
          <goal>manifest</goal>
          <goal>bundle</goal>
        </goals>
      </pluginExecutionFilter>
      <action>
        <configurator>
          <id>pde-maven-bundle-plugin</id>
        </configurator>
      </action>
    </pluginExecution>    </pluginExecutions>   </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
```

and plugin.xml

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.mylyn.discovery.core.connectorDiscovery">
<connectorDescriptor siteUrl="http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/.m2e/connectors/m2eclipse-tycho/0.8.0/N/0.8.0.201409231215/" id="org.eclipse.m2e.discovery.lifecycles.tycho" groupId="lifecycles" description="Tycho Configurator bridges tycho based projects and PDE" categoryId="org.eclipse.m2e.discovery.category.lifecycles" name="Tycho Configurator" provider="Takari, Inc." license="EPL" kind="lifecycles">
  <iu id="org.sonatype.tycho.m2e.feature.feature.group" />
  <overview summary="Tycho is focused on a Maven-centric, manifest-first approach to building Eclipse plug-ins, features, update sites, RCP applications and OSGi bundles. Tycho is a set of Maven plugins and extensions for building Eclipse plugins and OSGi bundles with Maven. Eclipse plugins and OSGi bundles have their own metadata for expressing dependencies, source folder locations, etc. that are normally found in a Maven POM. Tycho uses native metadata for Eclipse plugins and OSGi bundles and uses&#10;          the POM to configure and drive the build. Tycho supports bundles, fragments, features, update site projects and RCP applications. Tycho also knows how to run JUnit test plugins using OSGi runtime and there is also support for sharing build results using Maven artifact repositories. Tycho plugins introduce new packaging types and the corresponding lifecycle bindings that allow Maven to use OSGi and Eclipse metadata during a Maven build." url="http://eclipse.org/tycho/" />
</connectorDescriptor>
```