# Copy multiple dependencies into maven local reposiotry

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I have the following scenario, im working in project in a private LAN that got a private Nexus repository with private artifacts, when im outside of this network i want to copy these private artifacts into my .m2/repository for prevent that maven throw not found in repo central.

after copy these artifacts and run an `mvn clean install` or `mvn clean install -U` maven always says that did not found into repo central

There is a way to install multiple dependencies (without to use `install:install-file`, because i got arround 200 artifacts to install) or some command that force maven to rescan (also i tried with `purge-local-repository`) your local repository to re index their artifacts and find that got new one ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I configure Maven for offline development?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7233328/how-do-i-configure-maven-for-offline-development)

Comment: Simply run `mvn clean install` and than you go offlilne.  Copying artifacts manually is not a good idea..