# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/itextpdf/kernel/pdf/PdfWriter itext and gradle

Tags: java, pdf, gradle, build.gradle, itext7

I'm using Gradle to setup a test project that uses itext 7 to generate pdf files.

If I run my main class in Netbeans IDE everything works fine; a "results" folder is created and inside it I can find the generated pdf.

But if I clean and build the project, go into project_folder/build/libs and try to execute java -jar mypdfproject.jar file i get this error => java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/itextpdf/kernel/pdf/PdfWriter

this is my main class (MyPdfMain.class)

```
package com.mypackage;

import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MyPdfMain {

    public static final String DEST = "results/pdf/hello_word.pdf";

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     * @throws java.io.IOException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        File file = new File(DEST);
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();


        //Initialize PDF writer
        PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(DEST);

        //Initialize PDF document
        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);

        // Initialize document
        Document document = new Document(pdf);

        //Add paragraph to the document
        document.add(new Paragraph("Hello World!"));

        //Close document
        document.close();
    }
}
```

and this is the build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'

if (!hasProperty('mainClass')) {
    ext.mainClass = 'com.mypackage.MyPdfMain'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.itextpdf', name: 'kernel', version: '7.0.0'
    compile group: 'com.itextpdf', name: 'io', version: '7.0.0'
    compile group: 'com.itextpdf', name: 'layout', version: '7.0.0'
    compile group: 'com.itextpdf', name: 'forms', version: '7.0.0'
    compile group: 'com.itextpdf', name: 'pdfa', version: '7.0.0'
    compile group: 'com.itextpdf', name: 'pdftest', version: '7.0.0'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.10'
}

task copyToLib( type: Copy ) {
    into "$buildDir/libs/lib"
    from configurations.runtime
}

jar{
    dependsOn copyToLib
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.mypackage.MyPdfMain'
        //        attributes 'Class-Path': configurations.compile.collect { it.getName() }.join(' ')
    }
}
```

as you can see I created a task to copy all the dependecies jars into builds/libs/lib

task copyToLib( type: Copy ) {
    into "$buildDir/libs/lib"
    from configurations.runtime
}

and set jar{
    dependsOn copyToLib
}

but the error is still the same.

I think it should be a classpath error, but I don't know how and where to set the classpath in Gradle. How can I run my project from terminal?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your help. Using the application plugin is a good solution! Besides I found another way to solve changing my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'

if (!hasProperty('mainClass')) {
    ext.mainClass = 'com.mypackage.MyPdfMain'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.itextpdf', name: 'kernel', version: '7.0.0'
    compile group: 'com.itextpdf', name: 'io', version: '7.0.0'
    compile group: 'com.itextpdf', name: 'layout', version: '7.0.0'
    compile group: 'com.itextpdf', name: 'forms', version: '7.0.0'
    compile group: 'com.itextpdf', name: 'pdfa', version: '7.0.0'
    compile group: 'com.itextpdf', name: 'pdftest', version: '7.0.0'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.10'
}

task copyDependenciesIntoBuildLibsDir( type: Copy ) {
    from configurations.runtime
    into "$buildDir/libs/lib"
}

jar{ dependsOn copyDependenciesIntoBuildLibsDir
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.mypackage.MyPdfMain'
        attributes 'Class-Path': configurations.runtime.collect { "lib/" + it.getName()}.join(' ')
    }
}
```

Comment: If the 'application' plugin part helped out, you may vote my answer up ;-)

Comment: Ok. I've just voted you up, but unfortunately I've got less than 15 reputation points so I think no one can see my vote.

Answer (score 0):

You are copying the dependent jars to lib directory, and creating your application jar.
You need to define that in your classpath in command line. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5020566/564503)

Another way could be, you can apply 'application' plugin in your build.gradle :

```
group 'Hello-World'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

jar{
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.mypackage.MyPdfMain'
    }
}
```

Then you can do `gradle build` which should create directories `build/distribution`

You will find your application zipped inside that directory, which you can just unzip and execute the shell file from the `bin` directory (which you will see after unzipping. The unzipped directory will have a shell script inside bin directory.).

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded and added to the Build Path kernel-7.1.4 jar and styled-xml-parser.jar and all its dependencies from the location https://jar-download.com/download-handling.php and that did away with the error.
Note: if working in an offline maven enabled environment this problem can be addressed through running [**mvn dependency:go-offline**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7233328/how-do-i-configure-maven-for-offline-development) command from the location wherein the pom.xml file of the project is located.