# Move and IntelliJ/Maven project to another PC with IntelliJ but no internet access

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have a project in IntelliJ that uses Maven. I need to move the project to a PC that will have IntelliJ installed but doesn’t have external internet access due to corporate firewall rules.

What is the best way to grab the project and all of its dependencies so that when I set the project up in IntelliJ on the target machine IntelliJ will still see the projects dependencies.

Comment: You could enable download dependencies and move them to a "lib" folder in your project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to export the project and then zip the local maven repository (see here for reference https://www.mkyong.com/maven/where-is-maven-local-repository/) on the machine. If you transfer both and set maven to run offline it should work ([How do I configure Maven for offline development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7233328/how-do-i-configure-maven-for-offline-development)).