# How to have Maven build dependency from local Maven project instead of download?

Tags: java, maven

I am working on 2 Java maven projects A and B, and A depends on B. Both projects are github repositories which I have cloned on my local machine.

I made some changes to B and want to test it out with project A now.

When I run the tests in project A, how do I tell Maven to use my local copy of B rather than download a jar file of B from the internet?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I configure Maven for offline development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7233328/how-do-i-configure-maven-for-offline-development)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few possible ways:

1. Switch to offline mode with `mvn -o`. That way you will be only using local repository.
2. Build and install new version of B which is only available in local repository e.g. `1.0.1-SNAPSHOT`. Then update A `pom.xml` to use this new version.

Check out [Introduction to Repositories](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html) docs to understand what are repositories and how they work.

Comment: I vote (2) - so that it's clear you're using a version that is not the public one.  Even better, put your name in the version, rather than just updating the version number - to make it reallly obvious you're referencing your own version, not one that somehow hasn't made it to the public repo yet...