# Why is maven dependency:go-offline not preventing redownloading?

Tags: docker, maven, docker-build

I use `dependency:go-offline` to avoid redownloading in my Docker build. Yet the `docker build -t myimage .` causes the jars to be redownloaded. How can I prevent redownloading?

Relevant part of the Dockerfile.

```
FROM maven:3.8.3-jdk-8 AS build
COPY src /usr/src/app/src  
COPY pom.xml /usr/src/app
COPY run.sh /usr/src/app
RUN mvn -f /usr/src/app/pom.xml dependency:go-offline
RUN mvn -f /usr/src/app/pom.xml install dependency:copy-dependencies

FROM gcr.io/distroless/java
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/ .

ENTRYPOINT ["./run.sh"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-o` switch. This enables offline build.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/7233762/927493

Comment: Thank you. That might help or `mvn install` However, the redownload occurs  in `go-offline`

Comment: Also, for `mvn install`, the `-o` switch results in this error `Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce for parameter requireUpperBoundDeps: Cannot create instance of class org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireUpperBoundDeps: org/apache/maven/shared/dependency/tree/DependencyTreeBuilderException: org.apache.maven.shared.dependency.tree.DependencyTreeBuilderException -> [Help 1]
`